# take the result of html radio button button and place it into mysql database via php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to create a dynamic web page where i have 4 radio button like the following : 
Do you want to sleep ? yes No ( as button ) and a submit button.
Do you want to eat ? yes No ( as button ) and a submit button.

then I want to take the response and place it into mysql database. This is my php code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="action_page.php">
 <label class="heading"> do you want to eat ?<label/>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes_1" checked> yes
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="no_1"> No
  <input type="submit">
</form> 
<br>
<br>
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb';
$username = 'root';
$password = '1234';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['radio']))
{
echo "<span>You have selected :<b> ".$_POST['radio']."</b></span>";
}
else{ echo "<span>Please choose any radio button.</span>";}
}

?>
<form action="action_page.php">
  <label> do you want to sleep ?<label/>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="yes_2" checked> Oui
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="no_2"> Non
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="confirmer" />
</form>
<form action="iotpage.php">

<?php   
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb';
$username = 'root';
$password = '1234';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
//if(isset($_POST['submit']))
//{
//foreach ($_POST['radio'] as $select2)
//{
//echo "You have selected for hum:" .$select2; // Displaying Selected Value
//}
//}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created a table in my sql db named action and it contains 2 columns one for the first question and the second for the second question . How can I modify my code to insert into my db .

Comment: So you want to store Radio Button value in Database? Why you are using form two different times. you can achieve it on same form. Just Change the name of Radio Button

Comment: yes If the user selects yes for the first question I want to put yes_1 in my database and no_1 if he selects no . 
And same for the second question

Answer (score 0):

Put a form with a radio in your html

```
    <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <label class="heading"> Do you want to eat ?<label/>
            <legend>Options:</legend>
            Option One   <input type="radio" name="eat" value="yes"/>
            Option Two   <input type="radio" name="eat" value="no"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <label> Do you want to sleep ?<label/>
            <legend>Options:</legend>
            Option One   <input type="radio" name="sleep" value="yes"/>
            Option Two   <input type="radio" name="sleep" value="no"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

On your PHP side(if you use php) get the post value, construct you statement and execute it:

```
$eat = $_POST["eat"];
$statement = "INSERT INTO MyTable(option_name) VALUES($eat) ";

$sleep = $_POST["sleep"];
$statement = "INSERT INTO MyTable(option_name) VALUES($sleep) ";
```

Obviously this is to illustrate the principle you need to do a lot more if you want to create a nice code.